# ActiveJob inline queue adapter for specific jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activejob

Is there any way to set ActiveJob queue adapter to inline for specific background jobs?

In my case I'd like to run some background jobs in tests to build integration tests. I don't bother with job internal details since my purpose is just to run background jobs and assert the result. However these integrations tests does not cover all background jobs, so I don't want to set queue adapter globally.

Answer (score 6):

You can use RSpec's around_hook feature:

```
module WithQueueAdapter
  def with_queue_adapter(new_adapter)
    around do |example|
      begin
        old_adapter = ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter
        ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = new_adapter
        example.run
      ensure
        ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = old_adapter
      end
    end
  end
end


RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.extend WithQueueAdapter
end
```

And in your test

```
describe "My cool feature" do
  with_queue_adapter :inline

  # examples go there
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The [queue_adapter](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapter/ClassMethods.html#method-i-queue_adapter) class property of ActiveJob::Base can be set on any job class and it will affect the job class itself and any child classes. So you could have something like

```
class JobThatMustRunInlineWhileTesting < ActiveJob::Base
  if Rails.env.test?
    queue_adapter :inline
  end

  # rest of your job
end
```